# python BeautifulSoup findAll intr-txt

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i want to scrape all tag intr-txt from div 'class':'js-interests-list-wrap js-interests-board js-wrap' whit BeautifulSoup from this page : https://badoo.com/profile/0266965187. I'm write this code :

```
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
interese = parsed_html.findAll('div', {'class':'js-interests-list-wrap js-interests-board js-wrap'})
```

actual output is :

```
<div class="js-interests-list-wrap js-interests-board js-wrap" data-interests-type="hon-all"> <span class="js-intr intr"> <i class="intr-ico intr-ico--fashion"></i><!-- --><span class="intr-txt">Fotografii de modă</span> </span><span class="js-intr intr"> <i class="intr-ico intr-ico--food"></i><!-- --><span class="intr-txt">Mâncare de casă</span> </span><span class="js-intr intr"> <i class="intr-ico intr-ico--fashion"></i><!-- --><span class="intr-txt">Reviste</span> </span><span class="js-intr intr"> <i class="intr-ico intr-ico--food"></i><!-- --><span class="intr-txt">Gătitul</span> </span><span class="js-intr intr"> <i class="intr-ico intr-ico--food"></i><!-- --><span class="intr-txt">Să ies în oraș la masă</span> </span><span class="js-intr intr"> <i class="intr-ico intr-ico--travel"></i><!-- --><span class="intr-txt">Călătorii în lume</span> </span><span class="js-intr intr"> <i class="intr-ico intr-ico--hobby"></i><!-- --><span class="intr-txt">Fotografii</span> </span><span class="js-intr intr"> <i class="intr-ico intr-ico--music"></i><!-- --><span class="intr-txt">Dance</span> </span><span class="js-intr intr"> <i class="intr-ico intr-ico--hobby"></i><!-- --><span class="intr-txt">Fericire</span> </span><span class="js-intr intr"> <i class="intr-ico intr-ico--other"></i><!-- --><span class="intr-txt">Dansul</span> </span><span class="js-intr intr"> <i class="intr-ico intr-ico--hobby"></i><!-- --><span class="intr-txt">Shopping</span> </span><span class="js-intr intr"> <i class="intr-ico intr-ico--hobby"></i><!-- --><span class="intr-txt">Munți</span> </span> <div class="btn btn--sm btn--white btn--ico"><i class="icon ico--etc"><a href="https://badoo.com/signup/" class="b-link"></a></i></div> </div>
```

need output only in format text like this :

```
    Fotografii de modă,
Să dorm cu cineva în brațe,
 Munți,
 Photography,
 Reviste,
 Shopping,
 Dance,
 Fotografii,
 Dansul,
 Fericire,
 Bucătărie,
 Gătitul
```

how can extract like this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have already obtained all the `div` tags you need, now you need to extract all the `span` tags you need and then print the text out with `get_text`.  If you add this code to yours

```
interese = parsed_html.findAll('div', {'class':'js-interests-list-wrap js-interests-board js-wrap'})
for i in interese:
    texts = i.findAll("span", attrs={"class":"intr-txt"})
    for t in texts:
        print(t.get_text())
```

you will get this output

```
Shopping
Bucătărie
Fotografii
Mâncare de casă
Gătitul
Munți
Călătorii în lume
Dance
Tort
Să ies în oraș la masă
Reviste
Dansul
```